# Run Blender on Azure Windows virtual machine

Tags: gpu

I wanted to setup Azure's virtual machine to run Blender on remote desktop. My PC is lagging even in preview, I need to see what Im doing on my virtual machine, but I can't use GPU with Windows remote desktop. While playing animation, VM's CPU usage increases to 100% and FPS drop down to 0.4. I can't see my GPU in Task Meneger, but it's visible in Device Meneger. I updated the Group Policy to use GPU but I still can't use it. How can I force RDP or blender to use GPU? I have Nvidia Tesla K80 and the latest drivers.

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/configure-vm-gpu ?

Comment: Yup, and it did nothing